# Possible to configure https proxy for DXA connection to microservices?

Tags: dxa, microservices, sdl-cloud

I don't see any mention of it in the docs, but I was wondering if it was possible to set a proxy at application level just for the DXA web application connection to the discovery, content, model and other microservices? I will be using SDL Web Cloud with own hosted DXA 2.0 web application.

If not I assume I can do this with some OS level proxy settings in Linux, but as the SDL microservices are the only services I need to have access to over the internet it would be neater to solve this at application level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is currently no application-level support for proxies. Note that in case of DXA 2.0, support would be needed in the DXA Framework, but also in the UDP CIL.

So, this seems like an Enhancement Request for both DXA and UDP. If you think this adds much value, I would recommend to submit it as [an Idea on the SDL Community Site](https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas).

Comment: Thanks - I have done: https://community.sdl.com/ideas/sdl-tridion-dx-ideas/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/i/sdl-tridion-sites-ideas/application-level-https-proxy-for-dxacil